# How to connect to an IPython kernel existing in a Docker container through Jupyter console

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I started a Jupyter notebook in a Docker container with all the dependencies of that container. Now I'd like to have another console connected to the IPython kernel of the Jupyter notebook in the Docker container. How can I do that?